# Names of Graph Traversal Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

What I'm looking for is a comprehensive list of graph traversal algorithms, with brief descriptions of their purpose, as a jump off point for researching them. So far I'm aware of:

- Dijkstra's - single-source shortest path
- Kruskal's - finds a minimum spanning tree

What are some other well-known ones? Please provide a brief description of each algorithm to each of your answers.

Comment: Not really sure why this question was downvoted, it's a legitimate programming related question, and isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

the well knowns are :

- Depth-first search http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search
- Breadth-first search http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search
- Prim's algorithm [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim's_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm)
- Kruskal's algorithm [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal's_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm)
- Bellman–Ford algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm
- Floyd–Warshall algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm
- Reverse-delete algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse-Delete_algorithm
- Dijkstra's_algorithm  [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

network flow

- Ford–Fulkerson algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm
- Maximum Flow http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem

Answer (score 8):

A few off of the top of my head:

Depth-first and Breadth-first traversals, really just two different ways of touching all of the nodes.

Floyd-Warshall algorithm finds the shortest paths between any pair of points, in (big-theta)(v^3) time.

Prim's algorithm is an alternative to Kruskal's for MST.

There are also algorithms for finding fully connected components, which are groups of nodes where you can get from any member in the component to any other member. This only matters for "directed graphs", where you can traverse an edge only one direction.

Personally, I think the coolest extension of graph theory (not exactly related to your question, but if you're interested in learning more about graphs in general its certainly worth your while) is the concepts of "flow networks": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network . It is a way of computing about, say, how much electricity can one distribute over houses with a variety of power needs and requirements, and a variety of power stations.

Comment: Your comment is useful and insightful. Thank you for taking the time, and I've accepted the answer.

Comment: Correct name for "fully connected components" is *strongly connected components*.

Answer (score 3):

***Graph algorithms***

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms#Graph_algorithms

***All algorithms in one place***

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms

***Dictionary of algorithms and data structures:***

- Dictionary: http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/
- By area: http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/termsArea.html
- By terms type: http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/termsType.html
- List of all implementations in diff. languages: http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/termsImpl.html