# How to return first valid path?

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I have a large data set simulating a graph, which contains cities and the distance between them.  It is stored as a list of tuples:

```
map = [('Baltimore', 'New York City', 85), 
 ('Dallas', 'Cincinatti', 104),
 ('Denver', 'Salt Lake City', 91),
 ('Orlando', 'New York City', 17),
 ('Orlando', 'San Francisco', 64),
 ('Seattle', 'Baltimore', 89),
 ('Seattle', 'Portland', 44),
 ('Portland', 'Las Vegas', 32),
 ('Las Vegas', 'Reno', 7),
 ('Reno', 'Chicago', 29),
 ('Chicago', 'San Francisco', 56)]
```

This shows that between two vertices 'Baltimore' and 'New York City' there is a distance of 85.  I am trying to use depth first search and write a method that can take a start city and a final city and return one valid path (if one exists or if multiple exist) that will connect the two along with the total distance.  For example, if start_city= 'Baltimore' and end_city= 'San Francisco', it would print: YES, Baltimore, New York City, Orlando, San Francisco, 166. All I need is for my code to return is one valid path with the total distance.

```
def dfs_helper(map, start_city, end_city):
    stack = []
    visited = []
    adj_cities = get_connections(map, start_city)
    dfs_visit(map, start_city, end_city, adj_cities, stack, visited)

def dfs_visit(results, start_city, end_city, adj_cities, stack, visited):
    #mark start_city as visited
    visited.append(start_city)

    if(end_city in visited):   #soon as end_city is discovered, return the path it took to get there.
        return stack

    for adj_city in adj_cities:
        #add adj_city to stack to keep track of that path to the end_city
        stack.append(adj_city)  
        if adj_city not in visited:
            adj_cities = get_connections(results, adj_city)
            dfs_visit(map, adj_city, end_city, adj_cities, stack, visited)

def get_connections(map, city):
    connections = []

    for result in map:
        if (result[0] == city):
            connections.insert(0, result[1])
        elif (result[1] == city and result[0] != city):
            connections.insert(0, result[0])

    connections.reverse()
    return connections
```

And I call it like this: `dfs_helper(map, "Baltimore", "San Francisco")`

Comment: `sometimes will not even return a result because the data set is so large`. So, how many connection in your data set? Is it more then 10^9?

Comment: Construct a weighted [graph](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/) to model your objects and use [graph traversal algorithms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072964/names-of-graph-traversal-algorithms) to find your path.

Comment: @SakibAhammed Probably about 2,000 connections.  When I get to paths larger than 3 cities, this code will no longer run.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Please study the guidelines, they explain what your posting needs to contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return a path between two nodes in a graph, If it doesn't necessarily need to be the shortest, [Recursive DFS](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse326/03su/homework/hw3/dfs.html) can be used. It takes arguments `start_city` and `end_city`, returns the total cost from `start_city` to `end_city`. However, if you also need to print the path, You can print the predecessor vector. Here's an idea:

```
def dfs_visit(start_city):
   mark start_city as visited

   if(end_city is discovered)   //soon as end_city is discovered, return the path it took to get there.
       return stack

   for each adj_city of start_city:
       add adj_city to stack //to keep track of that path to the end_city
       if adj_city is not discovered:
            dfs_visit(adj_city)
```

Repeat this procedure until no vertices remain undiscovered.

Comment: I edited my code to reflect the dfs algorithm. I'm missing where it finds the actual path. Do you see any errors in my logic?

Answer (score 1):

Construct a weighted [graph](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/) to model your objects and use [graph traversal algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072964/names-of-graph-traversal-algorithms) to find your path.

In particular, [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) might be of interest to you. It finds the shortest path possible between a starting node and a final node. The first paragraph even gives road networks as an example of its application.

> Dijkstra's algorithm is an algorithm for finding the shortest paths between nodes in a graph, which may represent, for example, road networks.

As per the comments, if you don't care about finding the shortest possible path, a recursive [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) will also solve your problem with a smaller time complexity.

Comment: To return one valid path not caring about whether it is the shortest path or not, recursive depth first search would be the best fit, I think.

Comment: @ChuckLoganLim I edited my code to reflect the dfs algorithm. I'm missing where it finds the actual path. Do you see any errors in my logic?

Comment: Your `adj_city` is just a list of all the cities adjacent to `start_city`. Once you traverse past the initial city, `adj_city` becomes logically incorrect.

Comment: Try calling `get_connections` before your recursive call.

Comment: @ChuckLoganLim I made the change.  It looks like I still never get into where the stack should be returned.

Comment: Shouldn't you call `get_connections(adj_city)` to get the adjacent cities of the _next_ city you're going to visit?

Comment: @ChuckLoganLim Yes, that makes more sense. I'm still not quite sure how to use stack so that all that gets returned is a path.

Comment: What does your function return now?

Comment: @ChuckLoganLim Still just stack in that "if" check.

Comment: I mean what does it output for a given call and set of inputs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106319/discussion-between-chuck-logan-lim-and-cs-student).